# Групировка и получение количества записей по каждой категории

Tags: mysql, sql

Цель:

получить таблицу, где будут такие столбцы
1) сконкотенированные айди через запятую
2) Категория к которой они принадлежат
3) название категории
4)Количество айди привязнной к каждой категории

Что я уже сделал:

```
SELECT p.`product_id` as `id`, p.`category_id`, c.`name`
FROM `oc_product_to_category` p
LEFT JOIN `oc_category_description` c
ON p.`category_id` = c.`category_id`  
WHERE p.`product_id` IN(727,1025,742)
GROUP BY  p.`category_id`, c.`name`
```

сгрупировал по категории айди и имени категории.

Что еще нужно сделать, собрать все айди которые относятся к этой категории , сконкотенировть, и получить количество этих айди которые привязаны к этой категории.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

исправил. Добавил count(p.`product_id`) теперь считает количество. Остлась кокотенация

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решил, почемуто с первого раза такое не вышло.

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(p.`product_id`) as `id`,count(p.`product_id`) as `count`, p.`category_id`, c.`name` FROM `oc_product_to_category` p
```

LEFT JOIN `oc_category_description` c
ON p.`category_id` = c.`category_id`
WHERE p.`product_id` IN(727,1025,742)
GROUP BY  p.`category_id`, c.`name`